# What is the largest number of intersecting circles such that every pair of circles has an overlapping area?

Tags: geometry, elementary-set-theory

Think of a Venn diagram made of circles. You need to draw one such that every pair of sets is represented (and areas with more than 2 circles overlapping don't count!). What is the largest number of circles possible? I can do at least 4. (Is there a way to prove it?)

For the higher dimensional problem...

What is the smallest number of N-balls such that every M-tuple of sets is represented as shared volume?

e.g. for the 1-ball which is a line segment you can only have 2 sets to represent all pairs with the lines overlapping once.

Comment: What exactly are the constraints you’re looking for? Can you give an example and a non-example in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I see a construction where I place a circle of radius $2$ centered at each point on the unit circle. Each pair of circle overlaps since they all contain $(0,0)$, but this doesn’t seem as though it would fit your criteria.

Comment: Only 2 circles should overlap at once. Like a Venn diagram these areas would correspond to 2 properties.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbf{Lemma}$

-Two circles intersect each other in at most two points-

Consider a Venn-Diagram with three circles. Here you would have in total 7 regions $(A, B, C, A\cap B, A\cap C, B\cap C, A\cap B\cap C)$.

Adding a new circle you will get at most 6 intersections (two with every initial circle), which will create, at most, 6 new regions. Nevertheless, those are in total 14 regions at most, and you're looking for ${2^4}=16>14$ regions.

$\mathbf{Remark}$

It is possible to create a Venn-Diagram with four ellipses.

Comment: Yes but I can create a Venn diagram with 4 circles such that every pair is represented. (Not other combinations).

Comment: Oh, all right... Sorry, I didn't understand the answer then...